# Postgresql REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE - I want to get the file name without extension from the full path

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a series of filepaths in a PostgreSQL table and I wish to obtain the filename **without** the extension. Some sample data is shown (see also the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da48c568ffe9f4f0c06fdee375a45fac)) -

```
VALUES
(1, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file1.pdf'),
(2, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file2.py'),
(3, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file3.pdf'),
(8, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file8.tar.gz'),
(9, '/users/mcm1/my_prog.cpp');
```

Desired  result -

```
file1
file2
file2
file8.tar
my_prog
```

Now, I have been trying to grasp regexes (am a newbie) and I have made some progress. This is the code I have so far -

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(w.file_name, '^/.*/.*/......../.../') AS fn
FROM with_filename w
```

Result so far - there's a blank line before and after every other line - don't understand why!

```
fn

file1.pdf

file2.py

file3.pdf

file8.tar.gz

/users/mcm1/my_prog.cpp
```

Now, I've been having a number of problems -

I know that my regular expression - `'^/.*/.*/......../.../'` is a complete mess. Basically, I'm hard-coding the filepath into the regexp as you can see. I'm not picking up `my_prog` because the regex is too long. I'm not sure that my concept of repeating groups is right - i.e. `.*` (I started out with dots everywhere and after some reading, I got the dot-star notation).

Is this the optimal way of accomplishing this? I know that I have to be able to vary the number of occurrences of `/../..` - using this `'^(/.*/)'` perhaps?

Finally, my major problem is that I don't know how to keep the filename and eliminate the extension. There may be files that don't have an extension. I would be grateful, not just to have an answer, but also an explanation of what's going on in the regex! If there's any  more data required, please let me know!

Comment: You could match the regular expression `(?!.*\/).+(?=\.)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LINi57/4/). This uses a  negative lookahead and a positive lookahead, which I understand are supported by Postgres (but not lookbehinds!). In satisfying the negative lookahead, `(?!.*\/)`, because `.*` is greedy, the internal regex pointer is moved to just after the last `/`. `.+` then matches one or more characters, including periods, until stopped by the positive lookahead, `(?=\.)`, which matches the last period in the line.

Comment: I see from a comment below that you want this to work for file names that have no extension. In that case change the regex I suggested in my previous comment to `(?!.*\/).+(?=\.|')`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LINi57/5/)

Comment: In your last case, where an error occurs, I suspect that `'(?!.*\/).+(?=\.|')'` should be `"(?!.*\/).+(?=\.|')"` because the regex contains a single quote. I can't say for sure because I don't know Postgres, but many languages would require double-quotes in that situation. Also, rather than `regexp_split_to_table` do you have a function that merely extracts what is matched by the regex?

Comment: It's just a guess (since I don't know Postgres), but should `(?!.*\/).+(?=\.|'))` be enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: I see the regex I suggested in my first comment was incorrect. It should be `(?!.*\/).+(?:(?=\.)|(?!\.)(?='))`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LINi57/6/). That could be used to extract substings of interest, but I cannot advise on how that could be done in Postgres. Alternatively, you could replace strings with the contents of capture group 1 if you used the regex `.*\/(.+)(?:\.|(?!\.)').*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LINi57/7/). In the latter case try using Nick's `SELECT` statement with `'^.*/([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+)?$'` replaced with `".*\/(.+)(?:\.|(?!\.)').*"`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't recommend books, articles or sites to help you learn regex. I seem to have just picked up a bit at a time from various sources.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just in case you want to see [why](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190985/34007) I was interested in this topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here, matching everything after the final `/` (enforced by matching `[^/]` after, then using a lazy match with an optional `.xxx` extension to match the filename:

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '^.*/([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+)?$', '\1') AS filename
FROM with_filename;
```

Output:

```
file_name                               filename
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file1.pdf      file1
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file2.py       file2
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file3.pdf      file3
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file4.c        file4
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file5.java     file5
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file6.class    file6
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file7          file7
/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file8.tar.gz   file8.tar
/users/mcm1/my_prog.cpp                 my_prog
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a09def2504c93ac54825475aa8ab78b)

Comment: Thanks  - that was helpful - what is the `'\1'` bit for?

Comment: @Vérace the `\1` indicates that we are replacing the match with the contents of the first capture group `([^/]*?)`, which is the part which captures the file name

Answer (score 2):

I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    path,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(path, '^.*/|\.[^.]+$', '') AS filename
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The regex pattern used above is an *alternation*, and works as follows by removing either:

```
^.*/       from the start of the path up, and including, the last / path separator
OR
|\.[^.]+$  the file extension at the end of the path, should it exist
```

Note that this answers avoid the overhead of using a capture group.

Comment: That's great thanks. Only one "fly in the ointment" I'm afraid. I did mention that some files had no extension at all - and your code fails to clear that hurdle - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=328b5e7c0ce383554b69fbac7cc284e8) - your code is the first to run! Sorry about that - I know that it's frustrating when people come back with new info!

Comment: I have given you a workaround.  We can try trimming off the leading and trailing portions of the path instead.

Comment: Trimming before and after was the way I did it  in good old tradtional SQL! I'd be very grateful if you could show me another method also - if you have the time. I always feel that it's a very good way of learning - using different methods to do the same thing! It certainly helped my sql! I'll mark your answer as correct and helpful anyway! Thanks again and thanks for the upvote! 8-)

Comment: Honestly the method I gave above is probably the cleanest way of doing this.  I was thinking of using `SPLIT_PART`, but the thing is, we don't know the number of elements in the path.

Comment: I've used `SPLIT_PART` also. This is about learning for me -  I want to learn about regexs - easiest way is (v. old-fashioned) You can use `SPLIT_PART` also - the easiet is this `SELECT 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(file_name, (LENGTH(file_name) + 2) - POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name))),
      RIGHT(file_name, POSITION('.' IN LEFT(REVERSE(file_name), POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name)) - 1))),
      '') AS the_files
    FROM with_filename`

Comment: Nice. Do you need the `^` anchor?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Maybe not, but I would definitely include it here, because `REGEXP_REPLACE` is capable of making replacements in only part of the string.  Not including it might be debt for whoever inherits this code in the future.